# Missing elements of this 32-length list

Tags: cipher, sequence, letter-sequence

The following list has 32 elements. Element 8 and elements 22 to 32 are missing. Can you find why element 8 has been chosen to be missing? And can you find what are the missing elements?

1. RTKW
2. EHKB
3. NPKB
4. PBKW
5. NPKW
6. NQKB
7. NPKB
8. ????
9. NPKW
10. PBKB
11. NPKB
12. EHKW
13. NPKW
14. NPEW
15. RTKB
16. NPKB
17. NPEB
18. RTEB
19. NPKW
20. NPEW
21. EHEW
22. to 32. ????

I will regularly reveal some until someone finds the solution or only one remains!

Comment: Qbrf vg unir gb qb jvgu ahzore bs Bylzcvpf rqvgvbaf? Gbxlb jnf tbvat gb or gur 32aq.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be

> a bizarre way of identifying chess pieces, in the starting position of the game.

Specifically:

> Rooks are called "Tower"s, and knights are called "Horse"s. Then each piece is given four letters: the **last letter of its name**, the **first letter of its name**, the **last letter of its color**, and the **first letter of the color of its square**.

Then,

> the pieces are read out in diagonal lines, starting from the top left:
>
>  [image]

So:

> Number 8 is "GKKW", for the blac**k**³  **k**²in**g**¹ sitting on a **w**⁴hite square. Perhaps it was removed because "GK" is a unique string in the given pieces, and that would make it easier to identify the pattern  that the pieces were taken in?

[Also, a minor inconsistency:]

> It appears that after piece 15, all the pawns have their first two characters swapped. I believe this to be a mistake, but there may be something I haven't figured out yet.